# Insert ONLY TWO BUTTONS of Xib with NSBundle. Still show TableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sdk, xib

Im using a .xib file to add two buttons above my table view that edit and add to the tableView. The table View Was visible before the .xib was implanted but now I cant see the table. I have set the UIView BackGround of my SDK to clear by setting the opacity to 0%. All I see is the two buttons and white space. Is there anything I need to do in order to make sure my file doesn't take up the whole screen? Do I need to do something to my written Code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - if you set `UIView` alpha to 0 then you can not see the view that is for sure. try to set background color to `clearColor` beside of changing alpha to 0.

2 - `Table View` is not visible until you fill it by some data, if you put one `Table View` you will only see one white block.
So first fill up your `Table View` with some data and see what will happen.

hope this help

Comment: Everything You said was 100% correct but my problem was that I had set the "header View" to UIView instead of a unique View that didn't take up the whole screen.

Comment: I did not get what is "hearder view" and what is "unique view". could you explane more

Comment: Well Because the .xib I was uploading wasn't suposed to take up the entire screen classifying it as UIview was incorrect

Comment: No man you can have `UIView` in any size that you want. it should not be full screen. you can import one view in front of another by `addSubView` that both of them will be visible.